# Select Multiple Items from Excel Data Validation List

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How can I set up the ability to chose more than one option for a data validation list and list them in one cell? So  I have a validation list of A B C D. I want to chose A C D and have those three options display in one cell.

I only want to have values of A, B, C, D but I want to be able to select more than one value and have it appended in the same cell. So after I select A, I can then select B and the cell would contain A, B.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel: make comma separated list from column with blanks, fed by checkboxes](http://superuser.com/questions/482968/excel-make-comma-separated-list-from-column-with-blanks-fed-by-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do the same and found these great resources. The video and file download are specific to Excel 2003 but worked with 2010 ...should work with 2007.

Select Multiple items from validation list - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rH8N-Puvbo
Unless you want to rewrite the macro, you'll need the sample file download - http://www.contextures.com/excelfiles.html#DataVal

I downloaded DataValMultiSelect sample file DV0017 and used the LineBreak macro to separated each item by a line break.  I will simply hide what I'd call the "working column" which shows only the last value picked.

Note: I had no problem with the fiile download but will warn, just for the record: you should not download macro-enabled files unless you have antivirus software running with the lastest update and trust the source.